# How can I have a taxonomy list that shows parent child relationship, but not allow the parent to be selected?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Now and then I will come across a Drupal site that shows taxonomy terms to be selected in a drop down list. Example:

```
Fruit
    apple
    pear
Meat
    pork
    beef
..etc
```

And, while the child of each parent is selectable, the parent is not. How is this achieved, and how can I apply it to my taxonomy vocabulary who terms are 1 child deep?

Answer (score 1):

Download and install this module http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree and
 check the Leaves only(Don't allow the user to select items that have children) option under manage fields-> click edit on taxonomy field.

It will select only the children not parent.

Answer (score 1):

@Bala has a great answer for the node edit form, but it doesn't help with views filters or other front end displays.  For views filters try https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters combined with the [code I gave for another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104452/with-bef-collapse-expand-items-under-their-parent/266313#266313).  This allows your view to limit the selection of parents on the filter and is also keyboard accessible.

I will be working on a node hierarchical DISPLAY today and when completed I will post it as a comment on my answer that I linked above.

Comment: Link to my display in case needed.  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/266489/19071

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module.

From the project page:

1. Create a new field (type "Term reference") and select "Simple hierarchical select" as widget type.
2. In the field settings, check the box *Force selection of deepest level*.  This forces users to select terms from the deepest level, the leaf nodes in the tree.

The code looks cleaner than [Client-side hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs), which is another option.  Both modules are available for use in Drupal 8 and 9.  I don't recommend the original module, [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) because there's no upgrade path beyond Drupal 7.

*Thanks to [@mparker17](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/420/mparker17) for help on this one.*