# with BEF collapse expand items under their parent

Tags: javascript, theming, views

How to collapse and expand items under their parent using better exposed filter and Nested Checkboxes ..
What i mean ...that all the child items to be collapsed and they expand when the user click on (+ e.g) for the parent or check the parent box.
I am making a car dealer website and i need that to make an advanced search.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Update: any help please

Comment: You will need to write some custom JavaScript to get the nested lists to expand/contract. There are several jQuery plugins that will do this as well as come custom code [as shown here](https://drupal.org/node/990080).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue and here is the solution for any one want to do the same, based on this conversion [Collapse and Expand according to Hierarchy](https://drupal.org/node/990080)

add this code to your theme and you can use this module to add Javascript or CSS through the views page or block [Code per Views Display](https://drupal.org/project/cpv)

This code will add a + button beside the every parent, which will expand the checkboxes when clicked

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.betterExposedFiltersExpandCollapseNested = {
attach:function (context, settings) {
  if (!('$befSetupDone' in window)) {
    $('ul.bef-tree-child.bef-tree-depth-1').css('display', 'none');
    var $expander = $('<span class="expander">+</span>');
    $('ul.bef-tree-child > li:has(ul) > div.form-item').prepend($expander);
    $('.expander')
      .click(function() {
        $ul = $(this).parents('li:first').find('ul');
        $ul.toggle('fast');
     })
    $befSetupDone = 1;
  }
 }
 }
 }) (jQuery);
```

---

and another code which will expand when the parent checkbox checked

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.betterExposedFiltersExpandCollapseNested = {
attach:function (context, settings) {
  // first collapse the children
  $('ul.bef-tree-child.bef-tree-depth-1').css('display', 'none');
  $('.form-checkboxes.bef-select-all-none li').has('ul').once('bef-tree', function () {
    $(this)
      .find('input.form-checkboxes:first')
      .click(function() {
        $ul = $(this).parents('li:first').find('ul');
        if($(this).attr('checked')) {
          $ul.slideDown('fast');
        }
        else {
          $ul.slideUp('fast');
        }
      })
   });
  }
 }
}) (jQuery);
```

Note: You will have to choose (Nested Checkboxex/Radio Buttons) and check this option in better exposed filter

> Add select all/none links

---

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from Ahmed Hassan, I added functionality:

1. keyboard navigation
2. checkbox hidden on parent nodes
3. aria, labels and other accessibility functionality

   ```
   /**
    * @file store_better_exposed_filters_expand.js
    *
    * Provides some client-side functionality for the Better Exposed Filters expand/collapse of taxonomy terms
    *
    * Kevin Finkenbinder
    * Added keyboard interface, aria labels and functionality, removed checkbox in front of parent nodes
    * Based on the work of Ahmed Hassan (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/109214/19071)
    */
   (function ($)
   {
     Drupal.behaviors.betterExposedFiltersExpandCollapseNested = {
       attach: function (context, settings)
       {
         if (!('$befSetupDone' in window))
         {
           $('bef-tree').attr('role', 'tree');
           $('bef-tree-child').attr('role', 'treeitem');
           $('bef-tree-child ul').attr('role', 'group');
           $('bef-tree-child li').attr('role,treeitem');
           $('ul.bef-tree-child.bef-tree-depth-1').css('display', 'none');
           $('.bef-tree-child input').attr('tabindex', -1);
           var $expander = $('<span tabindex=-1 class="expander">+</span>');
           $('ul.bef-tree > li:has(ul) > div.form-item').prepend($expander);
           $('ul.bef-tree-child > li:has(ul) > div.form-item').prepend($expander);
           $('.expander').each(function (index)
           {
             $(this).attr('id', $(this).next().attr('id'));
           });
           $('ul.bef-tree > li:has(ul) > div.form-item > input ').remove();
           $('ul.bef-tree-child > li:has(ul) > div.form-item > input').remove();
           $('.expander').first().attr('tabindex', 0); /* tab to control but not individual elements - see accesssibleculture.org/articles/2013/02/not-so-simple-aria-tree-views-and-screen-readers/ */
           $('ul.bef-tree-child.bef-tree-depth-1').css('display', 'none');
           $('ul.bef-tree-child').css('list-style-type', 'none');
           $('ul.bef-tree').css('list-style-type', 'none');
           $('.expander').css('cursor', 'pointer');
           $('.expander').on('click keydown', function (event)
           {
             if (event.which == 32 || event.which == 13 || event.which==1) /*spacebar,enter or mouse click*/
             {
               $ul = $(this).parents('li:first').find('ul');
               $ul.toggle('fast');
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
             }
             else if (event.which == 37) /*left arrow */
             {
               if ($(this).parents('li:first').find('ul').is(":visible"))
               {
                 $(this).parents('li:first').find('ul').hide();
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
               }
             }
             else if (event.which == 38) /*up arrow */
             {
               if (!$(this).closest("li").is(':first-of-type'))
               {
                 if ($(this).closest("li").prev().find('ul').is(':visible'))
                 {
                   $(this).closest("li").prev().find("ul li:last div input:checkbox").focus();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   $(this).closest("li").prev().find(".expander").focus();
                 }
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
               }
             }
             else if (event.which == 39) /*right arrow */
             {
               if ($(this).parents('li:first').find('ul').is(":visible"))
               {
                 $(this).parents('li:first').find('ul input').first().focus();
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
               }
               else
               {
                 $(this).parents('li:first').find('ul').show();
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
               }
             }
             else if (event.which == 40) /*down arrow */
             {
               if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').is(':visible'))
               {
                 $(this).closest('li').find('ul li:first div input:checkbox').focus();
               }
               else if (!$(this).closest("li").is(':last-of-type'))
               {
                 $(this).closest("li").next().find(".expander").focus();
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
               }
             }
           });
           $('.bef-tree input:checkbox').on('keydown', function (event)
           {
             if (event.which == 37) /*left arrow */
             {
               $(this).parents('li:eq(1)').find('.expander').first().focus();
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
             }
             else if (event.which == 38) /*up arrow */
             {
               if ($(this).closest('li').is(":first-child"))
               {
                 $(this).parents('li:eq(1)').find('.expander').first().focus();
               }
               else
               {
                 $(this).closest('li').prev('li').find(':checkbox').focus();
               }
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
             }
             else if (event.which == 40) /*down arrow */
             {
               if ($(this).closest('li').is(":last-child") && !$.isEmptyObject($(this).parents('li:eq(1)').next().find('.expander')))
               {
                 $(this).parents('li:eq(1)').next().find('.expander').focus();
               }
               else
               {
                 $(this).closest('li').next().find(':checkbox').focus();
               }
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
             }
           });
           $befSetupDone = 1;
         }
       }
     }
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: Link to my display in case needed.  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/266489/19071

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to output the field in a hierarchy.  Note, I include this using Display Suite Code Fields, but it could easily be placed in a module.

```
<?php

function map_leaves($term_parents, &$term_tree, $depth = 0) {
  if (!isset($term_tree[$term_parents[$depth]->name])) {
    $term_tree[$term_parents[$depth]->name] = NULL;
  }
  if ($depth < count($term_parents) - 1) {
    map_leaves($term_parents, $term_tree[$term_parents[$depth]->name],$depth + 1);
  }
}

function output_term_tree($term_tree) {
  $return = '<ul class=msul_3';
  $return .= 'style="column-count:3;-webkit-column-count:3;-moz-column-count: 3;"';
  $return .= '>' . PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($term_tree as $term_name => $children) {
    $return .= '<li class="field-items">' . PHP_EOL . $term_name . PHP_EOL;
    if (!empty($children)) {
      $return .= output_term_tree($children);
    }
    $return .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
  }
  $return .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
  return $return;
}

$node = node_load(explode('/', $_GET['q'])[1]);

$terms = $node->field_library_space_equipment['und'];
$term_tree = [];
if (!empty($terms)) {
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_parents = array_reverse(taxonomy_get_parents_all($term['tid']));
    map_leaves($term_parents, $term_tree);
  }
}
unset($term_tree['Space Location'], $term_tree['Space Types']);
$return = output_term_tree($term_tree);
echo $return;
?>
```